# How could I create an auto expanding chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

If I have a  series of data in a1-a10 and created a chart from it and add a new line at say a9 then Excel neatly expands the chart to accommodate for it. But if I add a new piece at a11 the chart does not pick it up. If I create the chart including a lot of rows with nothing in them yet then those empty cells will appear as zero in the chart. How could I create a chart from a series of numbers in column A that auto expands with new data? Or how can I avoid Excel interpreting empty cells as zeroes for the chart?

Comment: Consider converting the data into a table. Then any additions/changes to the table are typically picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert your data series into an Excel data table `Insert>Tables>Table`.
2. Create a Chart using the Table as your data source.  As you add rows to the Table, Excel will add them to the Chart also.

For a similar issue and discussion, see this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/452850/how-do-i-get-a-chart-in-excel-to-add-new-data-series-automatically/452876#452876).